# Robot Framework how swith active screen

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, robotframework, sikuli

I need to change the foreground program in Robot Framework.
The programs are Windows. (ex: calc.exe or notepad.exe)
how can I do?

I use the Sikuli library but I can use others too

i have tried: Switch Window, witch Selenium library but correctly is wrong becouse this function switch Browser, not .exe

Answer (score 0):

A specialized keyword for that does not exist. It would be very difficult to implement one, because different way to switch applications on the different operating systems (or windows managers).
On Windows, we can use coordinates to mouse click, or keystrokes like Alt-TAB. Any strategy a real user uses, will do.
I recommend to use also, ImageHorizonLibrary for the keyboard control, because it has better control/functions.

EDIT: You now provided more information, so here is my *comment* about the use of `Click Region`. You should create a proper list and pass it as argument. Below is the documentation as we can see in RIDE Text Editor:
[image]

Comment: thank you very much Helio! with Sikuli library I am not able to click to coordinates.
if i try: Click Region    [344, 730, 32, 31] console given an error: argument type mismatch
Can you help me?